# Create DVD from MP4 using FFMPEG?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, dvd, video-conversion

I want to convert an MP4 video into a DVD using a Linux-based process such as FFMPEG. Currently we're using Nero to burn MP4 to DVD video, but I want to automate the process as much as possible.

When Nero creates a DVD disc from a single MP4 video, I noticed it splits the video into multiple VOB files. What's the point of this?

If I insert a DVD created by Nero, Windows immediately recognises it as a DVD video and runs Windows Media Player - perfect!

FFMPEG on the other hand just creates a single VOB file.

When I burn the VOB file created by FFMPEG to disc and then insert the disc, Windows does not auto play the disc. When I try to open the VOB file via Windows Explorer, it tells me the video might not be from a trusted source, though it does (eventually) play. Ideally I want FFMPEG or another Linux-based process to create the same DVD structure as Nero so that when the disc is inserted, Windows sees it in the same way as it would if Nero created the disc.

Is this at all possible?

Comment: To create a Video DVD, you need an authoring tool.

Comment: @DanielB you could move that comment into a full blown answer.

Comment: Theoretically, yes. It wouldn’t help the OP, however, because I have absolutely no idea what authoring tools are available for Linux and how to script them. @Reado Could you please clarify how the DVD should look? Instant video playback? Some sort of menu?

Comment: @DanielB, you did help me and a quick Google search came up with a working solution which fits my requirements. Plus there's a Windows and Linux version! Please post as the answer I'll award you the points.

Comment: related- https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2013-January/012989.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if you say so. ;)

DVDs consist of more than just video files. You’re likely familiar with how a DVD can have a menu. DVDs support a vast set of features rarely used like multiple camera perspectives, advanced playlists/branching (e.g. director’s edition and cinema cut on the same disc) and whatnot.

[All this stuff is held together by a program of sorts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD-Video#Directory_and_file_structure). This program is created by a so-called DVD Authoring software. Most of them are commercial solutions, but there are free alternatives like [DVDStyler](http://www.dvdstyler.org/en/).

Unfortunately, I don’t know of any scriptable tools, which is basically what you’re looking for.

Comment: +1 for DVDStyler. It was very easy to pickup and use for some quick conversions of MP4 videos shot with our cell phones.